# String Value to variable Name using dynamics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following class

```
public class MyTestClass
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

and I do the following: 

dynamic myClass = new MyTestClass;

string propName = "Name";
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
 myClass.propName = "Hello";
```

How can I convert the string into a propertyName using Dynamics? I know ways of doing it using reflection, but I would like to know for my knowledge if there is a way this can be achieved using dynamics or expando object?

Comment: `MyTestClass` doesn't have a property called `propName` How'll you do that using reflection? Can you show us?

Comment: that is amazing...how did you do that?

Comment: Can you indicate more generally what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you want to dynmically add a property?

Comment: Can I understand that you are going to assign the "Hello" to a dynamic generated property of MyTestClass?

Comment: I meant doing  like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824362/c-sharp-get-and-set-property-by-variable-name?rq=1

Comment: I have edited the code in question to use dynamic

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with the dynamic stuff, but I *think* you can use DynamicObject

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use DynamicObject, but it would be a little bit different than what you're wanting. I am not sure that what you're wanting to do is possible in C# (definitely possible in other languages though). This is a pseudocode attempt at *something* (maybe not the most amazing piece of code)

```
public class MyDynamicObject<T> : DynamicObject {
    private T referenceObject;

    public MyDynamicObject<T>() {
        this.referenceObject = new T();
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, Object value) {
        var propertyName = // get from binder parameter
        typeof(T).SetValue(referenceObject, value);
    }

    public T Compile() {
        return referenceObject;
    }
}
```

Then I believe you can do something like:

```
var propertyName = "Name";
var dynamicObject = new MyDynamicObject<MyTestClass>();
dynamicObject[propertyName] = "Foo";
var myTestClass = dynamicObject.Compile();
```

Overall, I would say that you should investigate the DynamicObject functionality. The function that I overrode may not be the correct one for an array (I always forget which function to override). But you should give it a shot. If you want to see a really sweet project that uses DynamicObjects in the best way possible, check out https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data