# Dynamically changing other class properties with a loop

Tags: c#, loops, class, properties

Let's say `strArr` is an array of strings. In a loop I split each of them, so I can get **key** and **value**. All I want to do is to find a property in `XClass` which is equal as **key** and set it to **value**.

If `strArr` element does not contain proper **key** (like 'propertyThree' in the example), property in `XClass` shouldn't be changed (so it becomes null).

Example code:

```
string[] strArr = new string[] {
    "propertyOne:valueOne",
    "propertyTwo:valueTwo"
}

class XClass {
    public string propertyOne {get; set;}
    public string propertyTwo {get; set;}
    public string propertyThree {get; set;}
}

-----
XClass instance = new XClass();

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++) {
    string[] arr = strArr.Split(':');
    string key = arr[0];
    string value = arr[1];

    instance.key = value;
}

// Later on...

ExampleMethod(instance); // instance's properties
```

This causes error, because `XClass` does not have property called `key`. That's obvious, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The keyword here is "reflection". There are plenty of tutorials/guides out there that teach the basics of reflection. There should also be questions+answers here on StackOverflow that demonstrate how to set a property through reflection using a given property name string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# get and set property by variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824362/c-sharp-get-and-set-property-by-variable-name)

Comment: I don't think `string[] arr = strArr.Split(':');` will compile...`strArr` is an array, not a `string`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetProperty` method of the type of `instance` to find a property whose name matches the string, and then call `SetValue` on that property to set the value on the instance.

If the property `name` isn't found, `GetProperty` will return `null`, so I used the `?.` operator to guard against that.

Also, there was a typo in your original sample - you were calling `Split` on `strArr` (the array) instead of `strArr[i]` (the string).

```
XClass instance = new XClass();

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
{
    var parts = strArr[i].Split(':');
    if (parts.Length < 2) continue;

    var propName = parts[0];
    var propValue = parts[1];

    instance.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.SetValue(instance, propValue);
}
```

Note that this code will work as is for the sample you provided, but `propValue` must be of the correct type (`string` in this case) for it to work. So additional error handling should be added to make this work more generically.